# Method inheritance for DRF views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, multiple-inheritance

Consider:

```py
class CourseListViewBase():
   def list(self, request, format=None):
      # whatever

class CourseListView(generics.ListAPIView, CourseListViewBase):
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
   def list(self, request, format=None): # Why can't I omit this?
      return CourseListViewBase.list(self, request, format)

class CourseListViewGuest(generics.ListAPIView, CourseListViewBase):
   permission_classes = []
   authentication_classes = []
   def list(self, request, format=None): # Why can't I omit this?
      return CourseListViewBase.list(self, request, format)
```

Why do I have to define the `list` method in the derived classes instead of relying on it being inherited from the base class? If I don't define it, I get a warning like this:

> AssertionError: 'CourseListViewGuest' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the order in which I listed the base classes. It seems like `generics.ListAPIView` defined a (degenerate) `list` method as well. So, this works:

```py
class CourseListViewBase():
   def list(self, request, format=None):
      # whatever

class CourseListView(CourseListViewBase, generics.ListAPIView):
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

class CourseListViewGuest(CourseListViewBase, generics.ListAPIView):
   permission_classes = []
   authentication_classes = []
```